# ValueError: Related model 'main.users' cannot be resolved. Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть модель users, которая наследуется от AbstractBaseUser. Я удалил бд и хотел сделать миграции. Одна из моделей мигрировала успешно, но модель users нет. Подскажите в чём проблема. В коде модели, менеджера или в чём-то другом?

Модель и менеджер :

```
# User model and manager
class usersManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, discord, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Вы не указали email')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Вы не указали имя')
        if not discord:
            raise ValueError('Вы не указали ваш дискорд')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            discord=discord
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user       


class users(AbstractBaseUser):
    # Основная модель
    username = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=250, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True)
    discord = models.CharField('Дискорд', max_length=250)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'discord']

    objects = usersManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Файл миграции :

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.5 on 2021-07-16 14:12

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0005_alter_examples_category'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='users',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('username', models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Имя')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, verbose_name='Email')),
                ('discord', models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Дискорд')),
                ('session_id', models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Сесия')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Пароль')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Пользователь',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Пользователи',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

```
File "D:\django\fouves\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\django\fouves\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 343, in create_model
    sql, params = self.table_sql(model)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 162, in table_sql
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 215, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1004, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1001, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 897, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 644, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 632, in related_fields
    return self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 936, in resolve_related_fields
    related_fields = super().resolve_related_fields()
  File "D:\python391\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 615, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'main.users' cannot be resolved
```

Если вам надо посмотреть другие файлы напишите в коментарии.

Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблема. Она заключалась в том, что у меня были другие файлы миграции. И они конфликтовали, я удалил их. И перезапустил всё. Теперь всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

А мне не помогает...
Из советов кому может поможет:

1. Передвинуть наверх приложение авторизации в INSTALLED_APPS (первой среди всех приложений)
2. AUTH_USER_MODEL = (первый аргумент это лейбл).(второй название класса)
   прим `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.CustomUser'`
   лейбл устанавливать в apps.py `label = "custom_user"`